# Loopback interface name on rhel 7 (and onwards)

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

If I run ifconfig command on my rhel7 machine I see below output:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x1.x2.x3.x4  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx
        inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx::xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
lo:1: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet x5.x6.x7.x8  netmask 255.255.255.255
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

Edit: I read about the predictable interface naming scheme, but it nowhere mentions about the loopback interfaces below.

[What does eno mean in network interface name 'eno16777736' for CentOS 7 or RHEL 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153785/what-does-eno-mean-in-network-interface-name-eno16777736-for-centos-7-or-rhel)

[Interface name assignment on RHEL 7 servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389065/interface-name-assignment-on-rhel-7-servers)

Comment: are you asking specifically about the "lo:1" interface? because your first link mentions "interface name 'eno...'" which could correspond to the non-loopback interface in your output (enp2s0).

Comment: yes specifically about the lo. The above link is just for reference. Yes it does mention about the eno. Just trying to understand if this naming convention is predictable, and if it will always be (at least rhel7 and rhel8) 'lo'.

Comment: Yes, the loopback interface is always called “lo”, although you’ve created another loopback interface called “lo:1” too.

Comment: nitpicking: `lo:1` appears as an interface only to `ifconfig` because it's using the obsolete (on Linux, for networking) ioctl(2) API which has been  superseded about 20 years ago in kernel 2.2 by netlink(7) socket / rtnetlink(7) API. Because on Linux the ioctl() API doesn't provide a method to *add* more than one IPv4 address per interface, it presents so-called alias interfaces. Any other part of the system knows only `lo`. eg: `iptables -A INPUT -i lo:1` will never match. Forget the use of `ifconfig` and disregard documentation using it. Use `ip link` + `ip address`.